# how to extract number sets in parentheses from Google sheet

Tags: regex, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, array-formulas

How to extract and split this set of numbers (314.81+10.00)+0.00 to each column

expected result:

[image]

Comment: Is this a formula or a string?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try in W1

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(value(split(regexreplace(V1, "\(|\)",), "+")))
```

and see if that works?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

like this:

```
=SPLIT(REGEXREPLACE(A1, "\(|\)", ), "+")
```

[image: 0]

---

and ArrayFormula would be:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IFERROR(SPLIT(REGEXREPLACE(A1:A, "\(|\)", ), "+")))
```

[image: 0]

Answer (score 0):

Well, in for a penny, in for a pound.

```
=split(substitute(substitute(A2,"(",""),")",""),"+",1,1)
```

---

You need to format the fields as "0.00".